# Convert ASCII emoji to hexadecimal

Tags: java, unicode, hex, emoji, utf-16

For the most part, conversion of ascii to hex works with this.

```
Hex.encodeHex(ascii.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
```

However, this doesn't appear to be exactly correct.  I was trying to convert "slightly smiling face" ascii (ðŸ™‚) into hex and keep getting "c3b0c5b8e284a2e2809a" which is correct but not correct.  The value I'm looking for is "F09F9982" which is easily figured out when doing an "od -x" when the ascii is put in a file.  You can even do it in Notepad++.

What I can't figure out is what the heck I'm doing wrong when trying to code a Java equivalent.  I even tried String.getBytes to UTF-8 and then take that to build a string to UTF-16 and still couldn't get the right results.  I keep getting "c3b0c5b8e284a2e2809a" for my result.

Anybody know how to generate the correct value?

I'm pretty sure I'm doing something dumb between UTF-8 and UTF-16 conversion but I can't figure it out for some reason.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The "slightly smiling face" is not representable in ASCII. Where does `ðŸ™‚` come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The character set you are expecting is Windows-1252, not UTF-8.

```
byte[] bytes = "ðŸ™‚".getBytes(Charset.forName("windows-1252"));
for (byte b : bytes)
    System.out.printf("%02X", b & 0xff);
```

output:

```
F09F9982
```

Comment: That was what I found out.  Thanks!